# Numix-circle icons not effective in Unity-greeter

Tags: 14.04, themes, icons, lightdm, unity-greeter

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and using the Numix theme with the Numix-circle icons. I like very much the unity-greeter as a login environment, is elegant and I think it goes really well with the Numix theme in my desktop, although the icons that appear in the upper bar of the login screen (the shutdown/restart, WiFi, battery, etc. icons) are the default icons, and I would like them to be the Numix-circle icons. Curiously enough, when I lock the screen using Ctrl+Alt+L the Numix-circle icons remain (instead of changing back to the default ones).
Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [*Ubuntu Tweak*](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) and change login theme and icon theme.

Download *Ubuntu Tweak* and run this command to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i <download_path>/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1-trusty2_all.deb
```

Once you have installed it, go to *Tweak* tab and select *Login settings*. To edit this area you have to *Unlock* setting (click relative button and insert password). Now you can select *Numix-Circle* icons.

[image]

I hope this will help you.